# Inserting data into 2 tables using a variable as the ID for the foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two MySQL tables (Lets say these are rough tables) Location is a multivalued attribute of the Delivery, so I decided to break it off into its own table

```
CREATE TABLE `Delivery` (
  `Date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Time` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `OrderTotal` float NOT NULL,
  `DeliveryID` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Tip$` float NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `Location` (
  `DeliveryID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `APT` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Street` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Address` int(20) NOT NULL, 
) FOREIGN KEY ('DeliveryID') REFERENCES `Delivery` (`DeliveryID`);
```

So what I want to do is say I insert into delivery with its own respective data, and add data to the location table with its own matching id to the delivery obviously. I've been told to break multivalued attributes into their own table. So what I have been doing is

```
INSERT INTO Delivery 
VALUES (DEFAULT, '12345','10:53am','admin','100','10');

SELECT @Var :=  Last_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Location
VALUES (@Var, '1234','address',DEFAULT);
```

My Question is, is this bad practice? Or is there any way to get around this, like just having a bigger Delivery table that has all Location data inside of it? My fear is, that say I have multiple users of this database somehow someway they will be able to insert into the Delivery table and mess up my synchronization in the 0.0005 Seconds it takes to grab the MAX(DeliveryID) from the table? For a project of this size I know it won't be a problem, but if this were to be a large scale project can errors crop up like I have mentioned?

Comment: Could you use `SET @Var = LAST_INSERT_ID();`?

Comment: I changed it, it gives me the same result as using max ID, which it should, what makes this more or less safe than using MAX(ID)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the last inserted id instead (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). Never encountered your method before of doing an extra select with MAX() and yes, it's possible for you to grab the wrong id with that approach.

Comment: With using Last_INSERTED_ID() would that make it any more or less safe? Or would the perfect method be just throwing Address,street and APT# into the Delivery Table?

Comment: Yes, it is more safe and sane to use. According to mysql, "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions. "

Comment: There was one time I've noticed iffy behavior with php and mysql and last inserted IDs, and that's when you use php's PDO and do a SELECT query after your insert query, but before grabbing the last inserted id (INSERT -> RANDOM SELECT -> SELECT last_insert_id()). You end up with 0 for some reason. Now it could be the framework I was using or something else, but I didn't really look much into it since it was an edge case for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's much better to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` because it is maintained by session.
Sessions can still be shared but it's definitely less risky that getting the max key from the table.

**If you have multiple sessions inserting in the same table, you'll certainly have problems with MAX()**

Keep in mind that LAST_INSERT_ID() only works for auto incremented keys.

An alternative approach would be to select the last item (order by delivery_id desc) from the delivery table that matches all criteria identifying an item as unique - ex. useraname, date, order total. Then you can have confidence that the record was successfully created and that you have the right id.

I would also recommend that you add a primary key to your location table.

Comment: Yes, `order by` is way safer than using `max()`